# Physics with Box2d and Andengine tutorial

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, gravity

Hello everyone I'm trying to develop a game like Jetpack so i want to set a gravity that normally push down and when the user tap the screen the gravity change it push up. I searched for a week a tutorial that explain how to do that but I didn't find what I search. Someone can explain me how to do that or post a link to a tutorial ?

Thank you !!

```
    main = new Sprite(sX, sY, mainTextureRegion);
    main.setScale(1);
    main.setFlippedHorizontal(true);
    scene.attachChild(main);
    mPhysicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0, SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH), false);
    final FixtureDef objectFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    final Body body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(mPhysicsWorld, main, BodyType.DynamicBody, objectFixtureDef);
    mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(main, body, true, true));
    final Vector2 gravity = new Vector2(0, 5f);
    mPhysicsWorld.setGravity(gravity);

    scene.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {

      }

        @Override
        public void reset() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the user touches the screen, you shouldn't change the gravity because it is not suppose to be done like that.
When he touches the screen, just apply a LinearImpulse (check if it not already at maximum speed) or something like that to make it go upper. The gravity shouldn't change as it should always attract all of your physics objects down. If your change the gravity you change the behavior of all your objects, not only the player one.

**EDIT**

To have the physics engine to work you have to call the step() method of the PhysicsWorld class at each render. The problem with Andengine is that you don't directly access the render() method as Andengine handle it at all.
So what you have to do is to register a IUpdateHandler on the Engine object that you return in your onLoadEngine() method.
This way the onUpdate() method of the interface will be called at each render and here you can call the step() method to get the physics part to work. The float value tells you about how many seconds elapsed since last render but you don't have to take care of that. The method is called multiple times per second.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT 2**

I think this should work :

```
//on the Scene object or on the Engine one
scene.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
        mPhysicsWorld.onUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() {}
});
```

Comment: Ah ok thank you.. But what i want is a code example of how to set the gravity... Known that, I can pass to the LinearImpulse :)

Comment: The gravity is set when you create the Box2DWorld. Then you can also change it with the setGravity() method.

Comment: Do you call the step() method of your World object at each render ?

Comment: I can't really help you for that, and there are probably good tutos for this. First your are supposed to extends BaseGameActivity, and then I believe there is a Handler that you can register on the Engine object. Just search the web.

Comment: But I have already done that !! My game already works and i have only to do this

Comment: I believe you didn't even search the web. See my edited post.

Comment: If i do mPhysicsWorld.step(); it tells me "The method step() is undefined for the type PhysicsWorld"

Comment: Search the documentation for it. It take some parameters.

Comment: Ok I made a mistake, I thought PhysicsWorld was the equivalent for Box2DWorld in Andengine but is it not. So I think you have to call the onUpdate() method of your PhysicsWorld object when your onUpdate() method is called.

Comment: I have edited my questions. What I have to write in onUpdate() ??? PLEASE GIVE ME AN EXAMPLE

Comment: It faaaals !! Aleeeeeeeeeee o o Aleeeeeeeeee o o !!! ThankYou so much. I know I am a newbie in this things but thankyou so much for your time